# How can i create cron jobs in specific files in Linux

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I want to have a separate folders fro cronjobs like

`/mydata/cronjobs`

now in that folder i want to have files likes

`backup_server` which will have the content like

```
30 3 * * 1-5 /home/user/scripts/backup.sh 
30 3 * * 1-5 /home/user/scripts/backup2.sh
```

similarly i want to have more files in that directory for each separate cron jobs

so that i can centralize and separate the cronjobs from one folder

how can i make root run those jobs for all files in that folder

Answer (score 1):

There is already a directory for this kind of little crontab parts. It is `/etc/cron.d`. You may find out that some programs, like `john` already utilizes this directory and puts scripts there.